# Unity for Fedora linux

Tags: linux, fedora, ubuntu-unity

Is there working Unity version for Fedora Linux? For now i found for Ubuntu and for SUSE, but nothing for Fedorians. Any details will be appritiated.

Tried the rpm pack with **dnf** command :

**sudo dnf install unity-...** with the provided version

A lot of things are going in the terminal - resolving dependencies, installing libs, etc. At the very end, no Unity working, or being able to be lunched.

Ideas ?

Comment: This guy seems to have posted a solution, I still need to try it myself http://allnightburger.com/installing-unity3d-on-fedora-24/

Answer (score 2):

Sure! I've just installed Unity on Fedora 28.

There exists a forum thread which is updated with the latest Linux builds available for download (go to the latest post):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2

The only dependency I needed:

```
dnf install mesa-libGLU
```